# javamail isSSL false even though I've set tls to True when sending mail

Tags: java, weblogic, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use javamail to send out an email. It worked in a java application. But i got some errors when i use it in my Weblogic web application.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "SMTPS");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "msg.petrochina.com.cn");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
MailSSLSocketFactory sf = null;
try {
  sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
  sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory", sf);
final Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication("dqlhgysbj@petrochina.com.cn", "123456");
}
};

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator);
session.setDebug(true);
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
  mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("dqlhgysbj@petrochina.com.cn","dqlhgys"));
  mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("dqlhgysaccept@petrochina.com"));
  mimeMessage.setSubject("test");
  mimeMessage.setSentDate(new Date());
  mimeMessage.setText("testMailContent","utf-8");
  mimeMessage.saveChanges();
  Transport.send(mimeMessage);
```

When i run the app I can see the following in my log

```
DEBUG: set            
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "msg.petrochina.com.cn", port 465, isSSL false
220 petrochina.com.cn [20137] ESMTP MTA v8.1.2; Mon, 03 Dec 2018 15:59:04 +0800
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "msg.petrochina.com.cn", port: 465
EHLO SUNWAY-DEV3
250-petrochina.com.cn
250-SIZE 104857600
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-STARTTLS
250 8BITMIME
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "104857600"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=LOGIN", arg "PLAIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
STARTTLS
454 tls initialize failed: ssl accept error. (#4.7.0) (eYou MTA)
    javax.mail.MessagingException: 454 tls initialize failed: ssl accept error. (#4.7.0) (eYou MTA)
```

It seems the application is trying to connect without ssl, and it won't connect.But i can connect the address with telnet.[telnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNJgy.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Then, remove the `mail.transport.protocol` setting.  ("SMTPS" is the wrong protocol name, it should be "smtps", but I believe it's being ignored because of the above problems, and you don't want it because of the properties you're setting.)

Depending on your mail server, you should need either `mail.smtp.ssl.enable` to use SSL when first connecting to the server, or you should need `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` to connect usingplain text and then switch to SSL/TLS after connecting.  You should never need both.

Hopefully that will fix your problem.

But note that you're using a very old version of JavaMail, which must mean you're using a very old version of WebLogic.  If possible, upgrade to a newer version of WebLogic.

Comment: thanks. it worked after i remove the mail.smtp.starttls.enable setting